# Removing Duplicates in an emailto string

Tags: vba, string, ms-access, duplicates

I am stuck on a little bit of code.
I have a form that when I click a button it sends all of the selected records into an email body with the email receipients that are listed in those records.

The portion that add's the emails to the outlook "To" section is as follows:

```
    With rst
      Do While Not .EOF
    strTO = strTO & ![EmailAddress] & ";"
      .MoveNext
      Loop
    End With

    olItem.Display
    olItem.To = strTO
```

As you can see form the code, it takes the String `strTO` and adds the value from `[EmailAddress]` on the record, as well as a `;` than moves to the next record in the loop. 
My question is, is there a way to create a global function that you could call just before doing the `olItem.To = strTO` portion of the code that would essentially clean up the string removing any duplicates?

edit: found out that I can post my answer properly rather than editing my question.

Comment: The best bet is to create a recordset that does not include duplicates. Check SELECT DISTINCT. If that does not suit, have a look at VBA InStr, that will allow you to check before adding an address.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately distinct will not work as I need to see the multiple rows for those but I do not need it to add extra duplicate email address to the To bar.
I am looking into some code I found online called RemoveDupWords2
which seems to do what I want, except when I go to call the function I type call RemoveDupWords2(strTO)
I get the ByRef Arugment Mismatch Error. So I am looking into that now.

Comment: Just use InStr as I mentioned, it can wrap around you current code and is fast and easy.

Comment: Can you please clarify to how I would use the instr? I am not too well versed in the instr but please don't just type out the code, I would rather understand how to do it. I will go watch a few youtube videos and read some forums to clearly understand.

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/instr.php You can check if the email in emailaddress is included in strTo and not add it to the string.

Comment: So while I see how the instr. works. Unfortunately it keeps looping the code.
`If InStr(strTO, ![EmailAddress]) then`
`msgbox "dupe email"`
`else`
`strTO = strTO & ![EmailAddress]` 
than the rest of the code runs. What I need it to do is notice the duplicate entry and not add it into the string. than continue the loop doing its thing. I hope this makes sense.
 
And by looping the code I mean it keeps popping up the msgbox. Now please understand the messagebox is a test to show that the instr is working. But how would I make it so it would not go into the string.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following function in a global module.

```
Public Function getUniqueString(txtToSearch As String) As String
    Dim initStr() As String, endStr As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, repInt As Integer

    initStr = Split(txtToSearch, ";")
    repInt = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(initStr)
        For j = 0 To UBound(initStr)
            If initStr(i) = initStr(j) Then repInt = (repInt + 1) Mod 2
        Next
        If repInt < 2 And InStr(endStr, initStr(i)) = 0 Then endStr = endStr & ";" & initStr(i)
    repInt = 0
    Next
    getUniqueString = Right(endStr, Len(endStr) - 1)
End Function
```

With this function in place, I call it out on the form when the button is pressed with the following code.

```
    With rst
        Do While Not .EOF
            strTO = strTO & ![EmailAddress] & ";"
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

    Dim strTOn As String
    strTOn = getUniqueString(strTO)

    olItem.Display
    olItem.To = strTOn
```

My understanding is what happens when the function is ran is it takes the strTO string and turns it into an array, so everything with the ; as the delimiter gets separated, than it checks everything in the array against the original string, if there are duplicates it removes them into the new string strTOn which is than called out by the olItem.To function for the outlook application.